# Terraform - assigning one group to each created IAM user

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

How can I assign during creation of IAM users with below code to one group existing alredy in AWS?

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "developer-accounts" {
  path          = "/"
  for_each      = toset(var.names)
  name          = each.value
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "developers-membership" {

  user   = values(aws_iam_user.developer-accounts)[*].name
  groups = [data.aws_iam_group.developers.group_name]
}
```

With above code I’m getting

> inappropriate value for attribute “user”: string required.

Users variable used:

```
variable "names" {
  description = "account names"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["user-1", "user-2", "user-3",...etc]
}
```

2nd part of question. With below I want to create passwords for each users:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "devs_login" {
  for_each                = toset(var.names)
  user                    = each.value
  pgp_key                 = "keybase:macdrorepo"
  password_reset_required = true
}
```

Output:

```
output "all_passwordas" {
  value = values(aws_iam_user_login_profile.devs_login)[*].encrypted_password
}
```

How can I decode the passwords? Below is not working as I'm sure missing some kind of loop...

> terraform output all_passwordas | base64 --decode | keybase pgp
> decrypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, the following should do the trick:

*You need to iterate over all users again and attach groups to each of them:*

```
resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "developers-membership" {
  for_each = toset(var.names)

  user   = aws_iam_user.developer-accounts[each.key].name
  groups = [data.aws_iam_group.developers.group_name]
}
```

---

To answer your second question: You are trying to decrypt all user passwords at once, which will not work as expected. Instead, you need to decrypt each users password one by one. You could use tools like `jq` to loop over `terraform output -json` output.

Just a small note. It's better to open two questions instead of adding multiple (unrelated) questions into one. I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser just figured it out same way as you did. About the passwords - laso thank you... and ok will keep this separated but this time it was related as at same time I was generating passwords in same module just forget to mention that - sorry.

Comment: One issue left however. I've got passwords in map output "user_name" : "encrypted_password". How can I decrypt this passwords one by oe as you mentioned? I was trying with terraform output passwords[0] | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt with no luck

Comment: You can alternatively use `for_each = aws_iam_user.developer-accounts` and then the user's name inside this resource block would be `each.value.name`.